# Codeblocks C Project - Header file redundant? (Why isn't it needed for the project to work?)

Tags: c, header, console, project, codeblocks

I'm trying to create a basic, simple project in codeblocks (console application).

This is what I have:

- main.c
- func.c
- header.h

Trying to make it work, i created a very simple program, filling all 3 files the way I thought they sould be filled (based on some guidelines I found online).

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    jogar();
    return 0;
}
```

func.c:

```
#include "header.h"
void jogar(){
    printf("Hello Mate!");
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
void jogar();

#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

All this works just fine. The thing I find strange is that **If I delete the header.h file, everything will still work the same way** (the output is the same). Isn't the header.h file needed for it to run? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My codeblocks version is the newest one (13.12).

UPDATE #2 - Regarding input by Aganju, I've changed the files to this:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    float x = 2.70;
    float a = jogar(x);
    printf("%f", a);
    return 0;
}
```

functions.c:

```
#include "header.h"
float jogar(float x){

    return x+1.10;
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
float jogar(float x);

#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

Now, with header.h included, the output is 3.80000 (as it should) and if I delete the prototype of the function in header.h, the output will be some random number. Is that what was theoretically expected to happen?

Comment: In older versions of C, there's a concept called _implicit function declarartion_; when the compiler sees a function for which it doesn't know the type, it'll _assume_ the function returns `int` takes some number of arguments of some types. In your case, this is close enough, so it works (note that if `jogar` didn't actually exist in another translation unit, you'd get a link error). Change your compilation flags to `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` and it shouldn't work anymore.

Comment: Just tried both and they make no difference. The compiler will still compile the project and the output it's still the same...

Comment: How are you setting the flags? It's possible you didn't actually change them.

Comment: Project > Properties > Projects Build Options > Other Options. Isn't that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your function `jogar` has any input parameters or returns anything more than an int, it will not work anymore, or at least you lose the compiler's matching capability (so you could call with a X but expect a Y and it would not tell you).

With no declaration in the header, the compiler will assume that your function gets whatever and returns an int, which happens to work for your case (In the early years, it was considered helpful to make the compiler assume that, so they do it)

Comment: _gets nothing and returns nothing_ - this isn't really correct. It's assumed to return an `int` and take any number of arguments of any type.

Comment: Just tried to return a float. I've updated the original question with the source code and the output. Does it confirm your theory?

Comment: yes. The returned float will be interpreted by the main program as int, which shows as some funny integer number.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It does make sense :). Apart from that, am I making a correct use of the header and implementation files?

Comment: yes. It will get more complicated once you have multiple files, but so far, yes.

Answer (score -1):

Do you compile the project after deleting header file.? :-)

Comment: This should be a comment.